# Save Figure generated from HeatMap() from Bioinformatics Library - Matlab

Tags: matlab, save, heatmap

I would like to save the image I generate the `HeatMap()` function from the bioinformatics library.

I cannot figure out to have the image without manually exporting the data.

I'd prefer to use `HeatMap` over `Imagesc` because it automatically scales the data to the mean.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the Bioinformatics Library for matlab, However you should be able to get the current figure with the function `gcf`. It is not the most stable way, but in most cases this will work excellent. Then you can save the figure as a figure or image with `saveas`.

```
HeatMap(...);
hFig = gcf;
saveas(hFig,'myName','png'); % You can use other image types as well and also `'fig'`
```

There is a second way as well. The `HeatMap` class also contains a `plot` method. This method may return the figure handle to the HeatMap plot then save the image with saveas.:

```
hHM = HeatMap(...);
hFig = plot(hHM);
saveas(hFig,'myName','png');
```

Comment: I think the first one does not work, because the "figure" returned by the `HeatMap` function is not actually a "figure", so when you call `gcf` it just spawns a new clear window.

Answer (score 0):

I share a part of a Matlab code that I used when I analyzed some data from TCGA

```
#I was considering two gene expression level taken from cancer disead tissue and 
# healthy tissues comparing them with this Heatmap
labela=Gene;
labelb=Gene2;
data1=[dataN(indg,:) dataC(indg,:); dataN(indg2,:) dataC(indg2,:);];
H=HeatMap(data1,'RowLabels', 
{labela,labelb},'Standardize','row','Symmetric','true','DisplayRange',2);
 addTitle(H,strcat('HeatMap',project));
 addXLabel(H,'patients');
 addYLabel(H,'geni');

    #I have allocated the plot in a variable
 fig=plot(H);
 # Then I saved the plot
 saveas(fig,strcat('D:\Bioinformatica\Tesina... 
         Prova2\Risultati_lihc\',dirname,'\HM.fig'));
```

But if you have to run one single object I advise against waisting your time in writing code (even if it is always a good thing to explore and strengthen your knowledge), I used because each time I was running a pipeline. Otherwise you can go on

1)File ----> Export Setup

[image: First!]

2) Export

[image: Second!]

3)Save in the format you do want!

[image]